# prism solution project assembly

Tags: c#, prism

i'm starting with prism, i have a solution in vs 2010 using prism,
one project(PrimUI is where i have the shell,
another project (PrismUI.infrastructure) is where i have for example region names class:

```
    namespace PrismUI.Infrastructure
{
    class RegionNames
    {
        public static string ToolbarRegion = "ToolbarRegion";
        public static string ContentRegion = "ContentRegion";
    }
}
```

then at the shell i want to do this:

```
<Window x:Class="PrismUI.Shell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"

        Title="Shell">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <ContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.ToolbarRegion}" />
            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.ContentRegion}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

i have to add something like this:

```
xmlns:inf="clr-namespace:PrismUI.infrastructure;assembly=PrismUI.infrastructure"
```

but i can´t find that assembly in the suggested list,
how can i resolve this,

thanks alot

Comment: Just to be sure, you've added a reference to PrimUI.Infrastructure in PrimUI right?

Comment: yes i did but i can´t find that assembly

Comment: Did you add the XAML reference and try to build? Was there a build error?

Comment: hi ryan,thanks for your responses, i forgot to make public the class what a mistake! thanks again it works fine now